# Are there permissions for associating work items with iterations in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops

Once an iteration's work item content has been decided on, is there any way in VSTS to prevent additional work from being added?  I would ideally like to lock down the ability to add content to an iteration to a few individuals (so that Product cannot sneak some items in).  If this is not possible, is there an easy way to check daily whether the content of the iteration has remained the same? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to "draw a line in the sand" as it were.

---

To track additional work in an iteration you can do something like this:

- Create a Work Item Query to find all WI's in the iteration you want.
- Save it
- Goto the Charts tab
- Add a "line" chart.
- Set "group by" to "iteration path".
- Pick a suitable date range.
- Pin this chart to your homepage.

Here's my config and chart for my dummy data.

[image: Chart configuration]

As you can see today, I moved more work into Iterations 1 and 2 and moved work out of the Backlog Iteration

[image: Chart with data]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  That provides a good visualization of an iteration growing.  Is there any easy way to tell exactly what was added though?

Comment: Your query could be sorted by `Changed Date` and look at the most recent changes. If it was really important you might be able to write an app to get all revisions of a Work Item and look for changes to the iterations through time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to "draw a line in the sand" as it were.

---

You could setup an Alert for Work Item changes that include the Iteration Path changing to the one you want people to stop using.

- Click the Settings "Cog" and then Notifications:
- Select "New Subscription"
- Work and Work Item Changed
- Next
- Add new Clause
- And select "And", "Iteration Path", "Changes to", "my problematic iteration"
- Finish

[image: Notification clause for Iteration Path].